# Deployment exception: Data Not Available

Tags: unit-test, deployment

Got a weird exception when trying to deploy a change-set to production.

[image]

On a sandbox all the test methods were successfully passed. But when tried to deploy to production it throws an exception with no any lines in a stack trace.

Comment: Unless we get your code ,its hard to help you buddy:)

Comment: May be the test classes are trying to access custom settings or some other data that isn't deployed.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, I can share code, but it will be totally useless, believe me buddy. As far as you can see stack trace is empty, so there are no evidences that will allow you to find an error.

I believe this is a platform bug and trying to find somebody who experienced the same error, and share some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` in test classes. but make sure that you don't use records outside of test class for validations, assignments or assert.

We generally get this error when deploying Lightning components or the org which has Lightning enabled.

This is a workaround only.

Comment: Did you contact support for this issue? If yes, what was their response, any recommendations? Do they provide the root cause of this exception?

SeeAllData=true - is a bad practice and this is the last think I would do.

Anyway thank you for this workaround, will try it in case support do not fix the problem.

Comment: @Yury I couldn't contact support as I had no time and support takes a day or more. I agree with you that seeAll is bad approach. Also, please let know the support feedback when you get